# how to get access to the checkbox in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a grid having two columns "name"(string) and "status"(check box),I want to save all grid data into database at once but i want string status = "P" if check box is checked other wise status = "A" for each row. How it is Possible. It an attendence project.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            string name = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string status = "";

            mscon.Open();
            mscmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into attendence (dat,nam,status)values(#" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "#,'" + name + "','" + status + "') ", mscon);
            mscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mscmd.Dispose();
            mscon.Close();


        }

        MessageBox.Show("saved");


    }
```

Comment: where is the checkbox?

Comment: Dont concat strings to create SQL. Always use sql paramaters.  Why cant you use the same formula to get the Status column as you do for the name column?

Comment: checkbox is in column "status", there is also a string named status and grid coloumn too,

Comment: `var status = (bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value ? "P" : "A";`

Comment: Also read about [SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt634277.aspx) and [Parametrized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: this is not working bro.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do when I evaluate checkbox per row:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["checkColumnName"].ToString())
            {
                // do checked thing
            }
            else
            {
                // do unchecked thing
            }
        }
```